# How to reference the result of a IMPORT function as a defined name in a single cell

Tags: google-sheets, importxml, google-sheets-arrays

Note: The motivation for my question is just formula readability. My sheet is working fine.

Let's pretend I have an `IMPORTXML` function that's currently returning 2 columns and a varying number of rows depending on the url used. So the expression is `IMPORTXML(MyUrl, MyXPath)`.

So the way I'm using that expression right now is `INDEX(IMPORTXML(MyUrl, MyXPath),1,4)` and this is repeated many times with just different row values. This is working fine, and in order for this to work it's not necessary for there to be a range on the sheet showing the results.

I would rather not repeat that expression `IMPORTXML(MyUrl, MyXPath)` many times over and over in my formulas, but give that expression a name and just use that name instead, in order to make my formulas more readable. So I want to say `INDEX(MyData,1,4)`.

Let's say `MyData` is in cell B10. What formula needs to go into B10?

Constraints (and yes these are integral to the question):

1. `MyData` is just in cell B10, not multiple cells.
2. `IMPORTXML(MyUrl, MyXPath)` is not expanded onto the surface of the sheet.
3. I can reference `MyData` just as `MyData`, not as `SPLIT(MyData)` or something.
4. I can't just stick `IMPORTXML(MyUrl, MyXPath)` somewhere and highlight the data and define a range name. Because the size of it will vary as `MyUrl` changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Sheets doesn't include a way to assign names to expressions (some people call them formulas) such `INDEX(IMPORTXML(MyUrl, MyXPath),1,4)`

You could use a named range, but that implies to add the expression in someplace on your spreadsheet and display the result, but you could hide that sheet.

Another alternative is to create a custom function but as Google Apps Script hasn't built-in formula evaluation you should find a way to do that or replace the referred expression for something that do the same but using JavaScript.

Related

- [How to make that a custom function update its result immediately](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/109054/88163)
- [How to use custom function with arrayformula?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/125835/88163)